# Vue.js router only loading component from navigation and not from URL

Tags: vue.js

how to solve this error in vuejs-
index.js?3672:101 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beforeEach' of undefined

Comment: Gonna need some code to be able to help...

Comment: In your router.js may be your router object is undefined.Check that once.

Comment: Seriously - How should someone help without seeing your code!?

Comment: Router.beforeEach(function (to, from, next) {

 // User is authenticated
 if (to.matched.some(function (record) {
   return record.meta.guest
  }) && Vue.auth.loggedIn()) {
  next({
   path: '/pages'
  })
 } else {
  next()
 }

 // User not authenticated
 if (to.matched.some(function (record) {
   return record.meta.auth
  }) && !Vue.auth.loggedIn()) {
  next({
   path: '/login'
  })
 } else {
  next()
 }
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Router);
export default new Router({
   // history:true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
 {
      path: '/Dashboard/dashboard',
      name: 'Business Intelligence Platform',
      beforeEnter: requireAuth,
      component: dashboard
    },
export function requireAuth(to, from, next) {
  if (!formSubmit()) {
    next({
      path: '/',
      query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```